# Code licensing change for all SE sites

Tags: discussion, licensing

I don't know why it's not on meta.stackexchange, but there's a post on [meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312598/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-stack-overflow-code?cb=1) explaining that there will be new guidelines for contributors starting January 1, 2016. Figured it's relevant here.

> Starting Jan 1, 2016, contributions across the network will be
>   licensed to the public under the following terms:
>
> - Non-code contributions will continue to be available for use under the
>     terms of CC-BY-SA
> - Code contributions will be available for use under
>     the terms of the [MIT License](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
> - You don’t have to include the full MIT
>     License in your code base. Contributors agree to give code users
>     permission to ignore the MIT License’s notice preservation
>     requirement, as long as users give reasonable attribution upon request
>     of the copyright holder (or Stack Overflow on behalf of the
>     contributor). This optional exception to the MIT License will live in
>     our terms of service.

and

> **What about other sites in the Stack Exchange network?**
>
> These terms will go into effect for all code posted after Jan. 1 on
>   all sites in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Could anyone explain in an answer what this means for the average user or should we take this to [law.se]? Perhaps [opensource.se] will take it as well, they like licensing there.

Comment: I'm hoping there's some clarification in the meta SO thread.

Comment: The announcement post has now been migrated to Meta SE.

Comment: @Mast You're more than welcome to ask questions at Open Source. In fact, we've already started to see some.